# Copy and Paste selected text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I want user to select text using the mouse, and then click inside another text box, then right click and paste the stuff from the clipboard to textbox.

I got the selection and copy to clipboard part working. However Pasting part is not working and because the copy part is wired to `mouseup` event. So when  user click inside the textbox the `mouseup` event fires again and overrides clipboard.

```js
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        if (typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined') {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var selectedText = range.toString();
            var startOffset = range.startOffset;
            var endOffset = startOffset + selectedText.length;
         
            var obj = {
                start: startOffset,
                end: endOffset,
                text: selectedText
            }            
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
            
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(JSON.stringify(obj));            
            
        }    
    })
```

```html
Select the text using mouse and click inside the text box->right click-> Paste
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
In this HTML tutorial, you will find more than 200 examples. With our online "Try it Yourself" editor, you can edit and test each example yourself!
</div>

<input type="text" width="500" />
```

Comment: I suggest that you first make sure that you don't need a permission. Try to catch the error, modifying your last line: `navigator.clipboard.writeText(JSON.stringify(obj)).catch(e=>console.log(e));`. Do you have an error?

Comment: You can add additional condition before copy the code from clipboard like `if (typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined' && window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString() != '') {`. So that it will not do any action when you click on your textbox.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado No, there is no error. I just need to stop overwriting the previous selection. I think Suresh's suggestion might work